# bash for loops not looping (awk, bash, linux)

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Here is a sample dataset (10 cols, 2 rows):

```
8  1   4   10  7   9   2   3   6   5
0.001475    10.001  20.25   30.5    40.75   51  61.25   71.5    81.75   92
```

I would like to output ten files for each dataset. Each file will contain a unique value from the second row, and the filename will contain the value from the corresponding column in the first row.

(example: a file containing .001475, called foo_bar_8.1D

See my code below, intended for use on the following datasets:

```
OrderTimesKC_voxel_tuning_1.txt
OrderTimesKC_voxel_tuning_2.txt
OrderTimesKC_voxel_tuning_3.txt
OrderTimesKC_voxel_tuning_4.txt
OrderTimesKC_voxel_tuning_5.txt
```

Script:

```
  subj='KC'
        for j in {1..5}; do
            for x in {1..10}; do
                a=$(awk 'FNR == 1 {print $"$x"}' OrderTimes"$subj"_voxel_tuning_"$j".txt) #a == row 1, column x
                b=$(awk 'FNR == 2 {print $"$x"}' OrderTimes"$subj"_voxel_tuning_"$j".txt) #b == row 2, column x
                echo $b > voxTim_"$subj"_"$j"_"$a".1D
            done
        done
```

the current outputted files are:

```
voxTim_KC_1_8?1?4?10?7?9?2?3?6?5.1D
voxTim_KC_2_8?1?4?10?7?9?2?3?6?5.1D
voxTim_KC_3_8?1?4?10?7?9?2?3?6?5.1D
voxTim_KC_4_8?1?4?10?7?9?2?3?6?5.1D
voxTim_KC_5_8?1?4?10?7?9?2?3?6?5.1D
```

these contain ten values per file, indicating that it is not looping correctly.

what I want is:

```
voxTim_KC_1_1.1D, voxTim_KC_1_2.1D, voxTim_KC_1_3.1D.....
voxTim_KC_2_1.1D, voxTim_KC_2_2.1D, voxTim_KC_2_3.1D.....
and so on..
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your loops aren't doing what you think because you are confusing awk with shell and additionally misunderstand shell quoting rules but more importantly whatever it is you are trying to do, your approach is wrong Explain what you are trying to do along with some concrete, testable sample input and expected output and we can help you. If/when you get an answer that tells you how to make your existing script produce the output you expect, just keep in mind that is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

You can use `awk` more effectively, for example this script will do the extraction of the two values from each input file and create 10 (or actual number of columns) files with the data

```
 $ awk 'FNR==1{c++; n=split($0,r1); next} 
        FNR==2{split($0,r2); 
              for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print r2[i] > "file."c"."r1[i]".1D"}' input1 input2
```

will create set of files for given input1 and input2 files.  You can use this as a template and get rid of the for loops.

For example

```
$ tail -n 2 *
==> input1 <==
8  1   4   10  7   9   2   3   6   5
0.001475    10.001  20.25   30.5    40.75   51  61.25   71.5    81.75   92

==> input2 <==
98  91   94   910  97   99   92   93   96   95
0.001475    10.001  20.25   30.5    40.75   51  61.25   71.5    81.75   92
```

after running the script

```
$ ls
file.1.1.1D   file.1.2.1D  file.1.4.1D  file.1.6.1D  file.1.8.1D  file.2.91.1D   file.2.92.1D  file.2.94.1D  file.2.96.1D  file.2.98.1D  input1
file.1.10.1D  file.1.3.1D  file.1.5.1D  file.1.7.1D  file.1.9.1D  file.2.910.1D  file.2.93.1D  file.2.95.1D  file.2.97.1D  file.2.99.1D  input2
```

and contents

```
$ tail -n 2 file.1*
==> file.1.1.1D <==
10.001

==> file.1.10.1D <==
30.5

==> file.1.2.1D <==
61.25

==> file.1.3.1D <==
71.5

==> file.1.4.1D <==
20.25

etc...
```

actually, you can simply it further to

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{c++; n=split($0,r1)} 
       FNR==2{for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $i > ("file."c"."r1[i]".1D")}' input1 input2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just with bash:

```
subj=KC
for j in {1..5}; do
    {
        read -ra a     # read the 1st line into array 'a'
        read -ra b     # read the 2nd line into array 'b'
        for i in {0..9}; do
            echo "${b[i]}" > "voxTim_${subj}_${j}_${a[i]}.1D"
        done
    } < "OrderTimes${subj}_voxel_tuning_${j}.txt"
done
```

Comment: The `echo` is probably ok here, but `echo "$..."` can do the wrong thing in some circumstances.  `printf '%s\n' "$..."` is always safe.

Comment: If `x=-n` then `echo "$x"` prints nothing but `printf '%s\n' "$x"` prints '-n'.  The same happens for `-e` and `-E`.  Also, if `xpg_echo` is set then backslash-escape sequences in the arguments to `echo` will be expanded.